# Allure report is empty

Tags: maven, allure

I try to add allure reporting to myProject,
but when I run

jetty:stop clean test -Dsuite=suites/android/login.xml site jetty:run

Test pass, but allure report shows 0 tests "Test run (0 testsuites, 0 testcases)"

[What I see in the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDnlc.png)

My pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.myProject.qa</groupId>
<artifactId>MobileTests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>suites/android/login.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <platform>android</platform>

    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>{latest-allure-version}</allure.version>

</properties>


<name>Mobile Web Automation</name>
<description>TestNG and Appium based project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-examples-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
          </dependency>






    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-java-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.16</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>






                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>


                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <platform>${platform}</platform>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
        open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <resultsPattern>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsPattern>
                <reportVersion>1.3.9</reportVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is missing dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
    <version>${}</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you see any XML files in target/allure-results folder?

Comment: Yes, problem was in my pom.xml!

Comment: @volkovs,@Yaka Ama, I am using allure with pytest. When I execute this pytest --alluredir = <filename> .xml files are not created and allure serve <reporting folder name> gives NoN% as result even there are some passed and failed testcase.  Do you have any idea?